# Update query fails to update rows value in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I have a form, containing a button to add DataGridView rows and another button to delete the selected row. I'm using this code to save :

```
    private void SaveReq2()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            this.mysql.sa.InsertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO molaak_det(MAXID,MALKID,AKARTYPE,AKARADDRESS) VALUES ('" + this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + "','" + txtID.Text + "','" + this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "','" + this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "')";
            mysql.sa.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}
```

The save process works good but, when I want to update using the query, I'm updating only the current rows. If I insert a new row and then I have to update, the code saves this new row in the database. Here my `UPDATE` query :

```
    private void UpdateReq2()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            mysql.sa.UpdateCommand.CommandText = string.Format(" UPDATE molaak_det SET  MALKID='{1}',AKARTYPE='{2}',AKARADDRESS='{3}' where MAXID='{0}'", this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value, txtID.Text, this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value, this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            mysql.sa.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Please, I need help to write well the `UPDATE` query. Thanks.

Comment: So your update query isn't working properly?

Comment: yes it updates only current rows but if i insert anew row when updating it does not save it only changes on current

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your update command is trying to update data types incorrectly... first things first it is pretty unsecure, you should at least parameterise the sql...

Have a read of this tutorial / example on how to do it, it is pretty easy, must more secure and much more type safe than what you are doing. http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

P.S. It helps if you could put details of any error, not just say it doesn't work... e.g is the power plug in on the DB server, is that why it doesn't work? :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand quite well your process.

You should execute, while adding a new row to the DataGridView, the `INSERT` query, because you cannot do this with an `UPDATE` query. 
Then, you have to understand in your control what rows have been added and proceed with the `INSERT` query.

Once this process completed, you can update the existing rows with an `UPDATE` query.

I agree with @PaulZahra, improve your queries using [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) objects.

Comment: after saving i open my form and call saved data by using aquery for this when i open say forgot to save arow where id =1 then i want to add it and doning will be update not saving anew so want to see what is wrong with update query

Comment: @user2746526 In your previous comment you said: "yes it updates only current rows but if i insert anew row when updating it does not save it only changes on current". You cannot insert a new row with an UPDATE query. Obviously, how can you update a new row if it doesn't exist yet in your database?

Comment: is there any way to insert new row when updating but with out repeat saving current rows

Comment: @user2746526 Executing only an INSERT query.